# datatable iterate through each row and col and do a calculation, and stored in another datatable row and column location

Tags: datatable

Need little help in the below code. I have a datatable, and need to iterate through each row and col and do a calculation, and the value must be stored in another datatable for the same row and column location..

```
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from ABC";
            MySqlDataAdapter myada = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myada.Fill(dt);

            DataTable datanew = dt.Clone();
            int oldVal;
            string newVal="";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count-1; k++)
                {
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        newVal = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][k]);
                        DataRow dr = datanew.NewRow();
                        dr[k] = newVal;
                        datanew.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oldVal = ((Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i + 1][k])) / 
                                 (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][k - 1])))*100;
                        newVal = Convert.ToString(oldVal);
                        DataRow dr = datanew.NewRow();
                        dr[k] = newVal;
                        datanew.Rows.Add(dr);
                     }
              }
         }
```

This is not resulting in the result i want. I want each of this newVal which is calculated from the iteration of the old datatable(row,col), must be added in the same location of the new datatable(row,col).

How can i achieve this..

Thanks